# Conditions on Date

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a condition on a recurrence trigger. I cannot seem to find any documentation on doing so with a date.

Specifically, I want to have a continue based on the day of the week (e.g, not continue on Sunday). Does anyone know of a blog post or MSDN documentation where they talk about date based conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the 'Date Functions' section on the Logic App Workflow Definition Language msdn page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn948512.aspx

Logic Apps do not currently support complex schedules, but one way of implementing the condition that you are after is to use the utcnow() function with a format parameter, like so

```
"conditions": [
  { @not(equals(utcnow('ddd'), 'Sun')) }
]
```

If you would like to see support for complex schedules in Logic Apps, you can submit a feature request via the Logic Apps Customer Feedback site:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: New Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language